# Layout laravel 5.6

Tags: json, laravel-5, layout-responsivo

Caros,

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório dashboard via laravel 5.6 com bootstrap, porém me deparei com algo que não sei como resolver no layout.

Este é o layout problemático

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esté é o excel que estou transcrevendo e como deverá ficar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

View index.

```
    @extends('reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.layouts.operacional')

@push('prepend-to-head')
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">

    <script>
        window.blade = window.blade || {};
        window.blade.chartData = {};
        window.blade.chartData.title = 'Contato Efetivo / Promessa de Pagamento';
        window.blade.chartData.categories = @json($horas);
        window.blade.chartData.lineDataset = {
            label        : '% Acordo/Contato Efetivo',
            data         : @json($perc_acordo_contato),
            isPercentage : true
        };
        window.blade.chartData.barsDatasets = [
            {
                label : 'Repasse',
                data  : @json($repasse)
            }
        ];
        window.blade.chartData.barsDatasets2 = [
            {
                label : 'Acordo Verbal',
                data  : @json($acordo_verbal)
            }
        ];

        window.blade.rosquinhas = [
            @json($capacitylog),
            @json($discagemcomp),

        ];
    </script>
@endpush

@section('dashboard-active', 'active')

@section('sub-content')
    <div class="row">
@include("reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.panels", compact('recebido', 'contatof', 'acordoM'))
    </div>

<div class="row">
        @include("reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.charts")
        @include("reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.table")
    </div>

@endsection
```

View charts

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title text-center" v-text="blade.chartData.title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
            <chart-bars-line
                    style="height: 250px; margin: 15px 0; background-color: white;"
                    :categories="blade.chartData.categories"
                    :line-dataset="blade.chartData.lineDataset"
                    :bars-datasets="blade.chartData.barsDatasets"
                    :bars-datasets2="blade.chartData.barsDatasets">

            </chart-bars-line>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View tabela

```
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <chart-doughnut
                    style="height: 150px;"
                    title="Capacity X Logados"
                    :dataset="blade.rosquinhas[1]"
            ></chart-doughnut>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <chart-doughnut
                    style="height: 150px;"
                    title="Discagem X Completadas"
                    :dataset="blade.rosquinhas[2]"
            ></chart-doughnut>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-7">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title text-center">
                Segmentação Ativo - Liderança
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                <thead class="bg-info">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Capacity</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Logados</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Segmento</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Mailing</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Contratos Discados</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Discados Unique</th>
                    <th class="text-center">%Penetração</th>
                    <th class="text-center">% Penet. Unique</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Completado</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Efetivo</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Acordo</th>
                    <th class="text-center">% Reversão</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Números Discados</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Spin Rate</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($intrahora as $tabela)
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Capacity, 0, ',', '.') }}</th>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Logados, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ $tabela->Grupo }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Mailing, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Contratos_Disc, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Disc_Unique, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Perc_Penetracao, 2, ',', '.') }}%</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Pent_Unique, 2, ',', '.') }}%</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Completadas, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Contato_Efetivo, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Acordo, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Perc_Reversao, 2, ',', '.') }}%</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Numero_Disc, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Spin_Rate, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>


                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

view painels

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Mailing Recebido
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-users pull-right"></i>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="lead text-center no-margin" style="line-height: 43px;">
                {{number_format($recebido->Mailing,0,',','.')}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Contato Efetivo
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-signal pull-right"></i>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="lead text-center no-margin" style="line-height: 43px;">
                {{number_format($contatof->Contato_Efetivo,0,',','.')}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Acordo/Mailing
                <i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc pull-right"></i>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="lead text-center no-margin" style="line-height: 43px;">
                {{number_format($acordoM->Acordo,1,',','.')}}%
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Contato Efetivo/Logados
                
            
        
        
            
                Valor

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Comparativo Contato efetivo
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart pull-right"></i>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-condensend">
            {{--@foreach($cincosegundos as $dado)--}}
                <tr>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        Valor1
                        Valor2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {{--@endforeach--}}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia me falar que painel é esse ?

Comment: é o que fica no topo da pagina, só que na edição do administrador ele cortou o codigo do painel

Comment: o chart e a tabela são esses 2 includes `@include("reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.charts")` e `@include("reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.table")`?

Comment: São 2 includes, vc acha que devo unificar os dois?

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz uns testes aqui, creio que seu problema é no `Bootstrap` em si não nas blades, tem um `.row` entre o `charts` e a tabela. troca as  `reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.charts` e `reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.table`, pelas que vou mandar a baixo e testa.

**reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.charts**

**reports.hora-a-hora.ativo.partials.table**

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-center">
                    Segmentação Ativo - Liderança
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                    <thead class="bg-info">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Capacity</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Logados</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Segmento</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Mailing</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Contratos Discados</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Discados Unique</th>
                        <th class="text-center">%Penetração</th>
                        <th class="text-center">% Penet. Unique</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Completado</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Efetivo</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Acordo</th>
                        <th class="text-center">% Reversão</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Números Discados</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Spin Rate</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($intrahora as $tabela)
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Capacity, 0, ',', '.') }}</th>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Logados, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $tabela->Grupo }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Mailing, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Contratos_Disc, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Disc_Unique, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Perc_Penetracao, 2, ',', '.') }}%</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Pent_Unique, 2, ',', '.') }}%</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Completadas, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Contato_Efetivo, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Acordo, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Perc_Reversao, 2, ',', '.') }}%</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Numero_Disc, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ number_format( $tabela->Spin_Rate, 0, ',', '.') }}</td>


                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Referencias:**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/